# Netty 4: How to send the same DefaultFullHttpResponse instance without getting a IllegalReferenceCountException

Tags: java, http, netty

I am writing a mock server using netty 4. You can give the mock server a `DefaultFullHttpResponse` that should be returned every time a specified request matches.

This works fine if the response is send at most 2 times, when it is send the 3rd time a `IllegalReferenceCountException` is thrown. As I understand the `DefaultFullHttpResponse` has its own ByteBuf (the http content). So when a response is send the reference counter tis decremented. This logic is not in my hand as it is done be the HttpCodec.

My question is: How can I use the same `DefaultFullHttpResponse` multiple times? I need to `retain()` the content when it is send, is that right? That is not a problem is all responses are `DefaultFullHttpResponse` but the mock-server is generic and allows to use other protocols and codecs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the response message implements `ByteBufHolder` like `DefaultFullHttpResponse` does, its ByteBuf can be duplicated.

```
if (resp is ByteBufHolder) {
    resp = resp.duplicate() //duplicates the byte buffer of the original message
    resp.retain()
    resp.touch()
}
```